# Javascript: variable scope question

Tags: javascript, scope

Why do I get here in the `alert` call an `undef`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use DBI;

my $db = 'my_test_db.db';
my $table = 'my_test_table';
my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db", '', '', 
            { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 1, sqlite_unicode => 1, } 
        ) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do( "CREATE TEMP TABLE $table ( str TEXT, num INTEGER )" );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO  $table ( str, num ) VALUES ( ?, ?)" );
$sth->execute( 'aaa', '111' );
$sth->execute( 'bbb', '222' );
$sth->execute( 'ccc', '333' );

get '/eingabe' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render( 'eingabe' );
};

get '/search_db/:col' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $col = $self->param( 'col' );
    my $term = $self->param( 'term' );
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT $col FROM $table WHERE $col LIKE ?" );
    $sth->execute( $term . '%');
    my $ref;
    while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {
            push @$ref, @$row;
    }
    $self->render( json => $ref );
};

app->start;

__DATA__
@@ eingabe.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        var ids = [ 'str', 'num' ];
        for ( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ){
            $( "#" + ids[i] ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ){ 

                    alert( ids[i] );  // <---

                    $.getJSON( '/search_db/'  + ids[i], request, function( data_from_server ){
                        var suggestions = [];
                        var len = data_from_server.length;
                        for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ){
                            suggestions.push( data_from_server[i] );
                        }
                        response( suggestions );
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td>String:</td><td><input type="text" id="str" name="str"" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Number:</td><td><input type="number" id="num" name="num" /></td></tr>
    </table><br />
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're having the problem that's explained here: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops%3a_A_common_mistake)

The reason why you're getting `undefined` in your call to `alert` is that, when the `autocomplete` function is called, your for loop has finished executing meaning your loop variable `i` has the value of 2 i.e. `ids.length + 1`. Therefore `ids[i]` is the same as `ids[2]` which doesn't exist as you only have 2 elements in your `ids` array. I've tried to come up with a simple demo of this behaviour to help illustrate what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/KwXVs/1/ (you'll need to have your browser's console open to see the results).

If you create an extra closure that should help preserve your scope and get rid of the `undefined` (see http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/BVa5Q/).

If you try changing your code to something like this hopefully it will get rid of the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function initAutocomplete(element_id) {
        $("#" + element_id).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                alert(element_id);  // <---

                $.getJSON('/search_db/' + element_id, request, function (data_from_server) {
                    var suggestions = [];
                    var len = data_from_server.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        suggestions.push(data_from_server[i]);
                    }
                    response(suggestions);
                });
            }
        });        
    }

    var ids = ['str', 'num'];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var current_id = ids[i];
        initAutocomplete(current_id);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was trying to say but I was in to much of a hurry. Good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `i` iteration variable twice: it is used inside of your callback to `$.getJSON` call again.

you should rename that one to a different name, `j` (just an example).

so it would say:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var ids = [ 'str', 'num' ];
    for ( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ){
        $( "#" + ids[i] ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ){ 

                alert( ids[i] );  // <---

                $.getJSON( '/search_db/'  + ids[i], request, function( data_from_server ){
                    var suggestions = [];
                    var len = data_from_server.length;
                    for( var j = 0; j < len; j++ ){
                        suggestions.push( data_from_server[j] );
                    }
                    response( suggestions );
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

i hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't see that and normally I wouldn't do that. But as far as I know in JavaScript the scope of a variable is a function so in my theory the second `var i` should mess with the first `var i` outside the function in which is declared the second `var i`.

Answer (score 0):

You source callback function is out of scope. When you attack a function to an event link that it gets called when the event is triggered which is after your for loop has completed.

A good rule of thumb whenever your are using callbacks is to always pass in everything that that function requires or attach everything that object requires to the window object and back it global.